# Why level-down shifters

Tags: level-shifting

I am considering a dual-Vdd circuit design, Vdd_H is 0.6V, Vdd_L is 0.35V. I understand that I need level-up shifters to convert the Vdd_L domain signals to Vdd_H signals, to have enough drive. While I am not sure do I also need a level-down shifter to convert the Vdd_H signals to Vdd_L ones? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you put too high of a voltage into a pin that is only designed for a low voltage you will hurt it.  Check your data sheet for the absolute maximums on those pins to be sure.

Comment: I have never worked with 0.6V or 0.35V logic. Are you working on an ASIC? This doesn't sound like a board level design. But What your question amounts to is this: will the 0.35V logic safely tolerate 0.6V inputs? My guess is that it will NOT tolerate it, but that is what you need to check.

Comment: @mkeith  Like you, I'm also curious as to what kinds of devices use 0.6V or 0.35V logic.  (?)

Comment: Thanks, everyone. This is what exactly I am doing: I am designing a SoC whose nominal Vdd is 0.35V. While I am considering doing Voltage boost (upscaling the Vdd to 0.6V)for some part of the SoC. So do you mean: if there is a way to design a device that can work safely both on 0.6V and 0.35V, there will be no need to have such level-down shifters in this design? Thanks,

Comment: @monkinsane Not exactly. Can the gates on the 0.35 V logic NMOS safely withstand 0.6V levels? Or will the gate in the MOS structure break down at that level? It is a matter of how thick the insulation is, I guess. This is outside my experience.

Comment: The PDK (Process design Kit) will describe what the maximum values that the transistors can handle.  More information is needed but I suspect that you are operating a low voltage process at lower than normal voltages.

Comment: Hmm...so it is a entirely device issue... I think this is what I tried to find: is it possible that the device can safely work on both these voltages? Is there any fundamental obstacle for that?

Comment: And is this true: the only purpose of level-down shifter is protecting (e.g. avoid break-down)?